# Ayuda get_the_terms wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Buenas tengo este codigo en php, y ha raiz de tener los sectores saldran unos iconos u otros. Pero no se como obtener los sectores con get_the_terms.La taxonomia es sectores.

```
echo ("<div class='iconos-sectores' style='display:flex;width:100%; 
 margin-top:20px;'>");
                "sectores" => get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'sectores' );
    echo ("</div>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma de usar [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) es pasándole como parámetro el `ID` del `post` y el nombre de la `taxonimía`, en tu caso `sectores`.

```
foreach (get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'sectores') as $sector) {
    print_r($sector);
}
```

Esto te devolverá un objeto cuyas propiedades son las siguientes, esto es el contenido de la variable `$sector`:

```
WP_Term Object
(
[term_id]          => 'xxx'
[name]             => 'xxx'
[slug]             => 'xxx'
[term_group]       => 'xxx'
[term_taxonomy_id] => 'xxx'
[taxonomy]         => 'xxx'
[description]      => 'xxx'
[parent]           => 'xxx'
[count]            => 'xxx'
[filter]           => 'xxx'
)
```

Si lo que quieres es asignarle un icono según el nombre (no me ha quedado muy claro lo que preguntas) puedes hacer algo así:

```
echo ("<div class='iconos-sectores' style='display:flex;width:100%; margin-top:20px;'>");
    foreach (get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'sectores') as $sector) {
     if($sector->name === 'nombre_buscado'){
      echo ("Icono Deseado");
      }
    }
echo ("</div>");
```